# Is it possible to make a Vlookup Table Array dynamic and have a change in lookup value in the same column?

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I'm working on a macro to allow for faster responses to a form for Uni Students. In the code I'm looking to use a Vlookup on a column to be able to BCC the university team that is related to the students course. I am able to get the Vlookup to work for one singular Course Cell but as I go down the rows i'm still only pulling through that original Cell value, despite the fact that all my other information that i'm pulling through on to the email have changed. Is it possible to make the code so that if I go down a line (therefore wanting to Vlookup the response on line M4) that I can do this?

See Below for what I have written for the Vlookup specifically (obviously theres more code and screen shot is attached if that helps)
<**Strprogemail = Application.WorksheetFunction.Vlookup(Range("M3"), Range("UG!A:B"), 2, False)**>

and then later on when setting up the email this is linked to: ***MailItem.BCC = Strprogemail*** (note I have set up the creation of email and all the necessary code correctly just thought I'd highlight where I'm trying to use the Vlookup)

```
***`enter code here`'Setup data to grab from spreadsheet

    Dim StrSurname As String
    Dim StrFName As String
    Dim StrStudentID As String
    Dim StrEmail As String
    Dim StrModTitle As String
    Dim StrModCode As String
    Dim StrOrgDeadline As String
    Dim StrNewDeadline As String
    Dim StrAcademicYear As String
    Dim StrYrofStudy As String
    Dim StrModLead As String
    Dim StrSignature As String
    Dim Strprogemail As String
    
'setup interface to Outlook
    Dim OL As Outlook.Application
    Dim MailItem As Outlook.MailItem
    Set OL = New Outlook.Application
    
    
'grab the data from the spreadsheet
'doesn't matter where we are on the row but we assume the activerow

       StrSurname = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 6 - ActiveCell.Column).Value
       StrFName = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 7 - ActiveCell.Column).Value
       StrStudentID = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 8 - ActiveCell.Column).Value
       StrEmail = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 9 - ActiveCell.Column).Value
       StrModCode = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 21 - ActiveCell.Column).Value
       StrModTitle = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 20 - ActiveCell.Column).Value
       StrOrgDeadline = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 25 - ActiveCell.Column).Value
       StrNewDeadline = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 26 - ActiveCell.Column).Value
       StrAcademicYear = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 10 - ActiveCell.Column).Value
       StrYrofStudy = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 15 - ActiveCell.Column).Value
       StrModLead = ActiveCell.Offset(0, 22 - ActiveCell.Column).Value
       
'Vlookup of Email addresses based on programme selected

    
    Strprogemail = Application.WorksheetFunction.Vlookup(Range("M3"), Range("UG!A:B"), 2, False)

'now create email
    Set MailItem = OL.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    MailItem.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
    MailItem.Display
    StrSignature = MailItem.HTMLBody
    
    MailItem.To = StrEmail
    MailItem.BCC = Strprogemail
    MailItem.Subject = "Extension declined - does not meet University Criteria"
    
    MailItem.HTMLBody = "<p>Dear " & StrFName & " " & StrSurname & "</P>"***
```

Comment: Use something more dynamic than `Range("M3")`?

Comment: It sounds like `.find()` or `.findnext()` may be helpful here, as a `vlookup()`, similar to `match()`, will return the first instance and stop.  You could also use a loop.

Comment: Please paste the actual code, and use the markdown to show it as code, instead of a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Quick example of loop to generate a list of contacts for Outlook:

```
for rowNum = firstRow to lastRow
    Strprogemail  = Strprogemail & ";" & cellValue
next rowNum
```

Assumes the `cellValue` is a valid email address.

Add an `If` statement to check for criteria, and if true, then add the name to list.